# C#: How to make a method call on a static member of an existing object

Tags: c#

So I'm performing tests on a dll with the following:

```
--test.dll--
namespace MyNamespace
{
    internal class foo
    {
        private static bar myBarClass = new bar();
    ]

    internal class bar
    {
        public void aMethod();
    }
}
----
```

Now in another program I have an existing instance of foo (obtained via reflection).  Now I want to call the method aMethod() from the myBarClass within the existing instance of foo.  Not sure how to do this.

```
foo myFooObject = GetInstanceOfFoo();  //i get an instance of foo via reflection

Assembly testAssembly= Assembly.LoadFrom(c:\test.dll);
object o = testAssembly.CreateInstance("MyNamespace.bar");
Type t = o.GetType();
BindingFlags bf = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod("aMethod", bf);
mi.Invoke(<notsurewhatgoeshere!>, null);
```

I am able to get the correct method info. My question is in mi.Invoke, how to I invoke the method on the already existing instance of foo.bar?

Thanks

Comment: Are you _sure_ you should be using reflection?

Comment: I believe you pass the o instance...not 100% so not posting as answer...

Comment: @SLaks I assume (hope) @Justin has no choice - if he had control over the code in `test.dll`, the solution would surely be to just expose that instance and its method...

Comment: @Aaron: That was my first thought after a cursory glance, too, but all of the reflection is just confusing us. He doesn't even need an instance of `foo`.

Comment: @djacobson: Given that `foo` is explicitly typed in his example code, I'm not sure that's the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var myBarClass = testAssembly.GetType("MyNamespace.foo")
                             .GetField("myBarClass", BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                                     BindingFlags.Static)
                             .GetValue(null);
mi.Invoke(myBarClass, null);
```

Note that you do not need to construct your own instance (as you already are) because you won't be using it anyway.

So the complete code you would use is:

```
Assembly testAssembly= Assembly.LoadFrom(@"c:\test.dll");
Type t = testAssembly.GetType("MyNamespace.bar");
BindingFlags bf = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod("aMethod", bf);
object myBarClass = testAssembly.GetType("MyNamespace.foo")
                                .GetField("myBarClass", BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                                        BindingFlags.Static)
                                .GetValue(null);
mi.Invoke(myBarClass, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

`myBarClass` is a static field.

It has nothing to do with any single instance of `foo`.

To get the object in a private static field from a class, you can write

```
var type = testAssembly.GetType("MyNamespace.bar");
var field = type.GetField("myBarClass", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
object value = field.GetValue(null);
```

Comment: You do need reflection.  (1) The type and field are not public, and (2) they are loaded dynamically.

Comment: I can't access myBarClass because it is internal?

Answer (score 0):

To do via reflection, pass in null to your method info.  You'll also have to pass in the `Static` binding flag.

```
var methodinfo = o.GetMethod("aMethod", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
methodinfo.Invoke(null, null);
```